# How to modify process preemption policies (like RR time-slices) in XV6?

Tags: operating-system, xv6, preemption

Right now it seems that on every click tick, the running process is preempted and forced to yield the processor, I have thoroughly investigated the code-base and the only relevant part of the code to process preemption is below (in **trap.c**):

```
// Force process to give up CPU on clock tick.
// If interrupts were on while locks held, would need to check nlock.

if(myproc() && myproc() -> state == RUNNING && tf -> trapno == T_IRQ0 + IRQ_TIMER)
    yield();
```

I guess that timing is specified in `T_IRQ0 + IRQ_TIMER`, but I can't figure out how these two can be modified, these two are specified in **trap.h**:

```
#define T_IRQ0          32      // IRQ 0 corresponds to int T_IRQ

#define IRQ_TIMER        0
```

I wonder how I can change the default RR scheduling time-slice (which is right now 1 clock tick, fir example make it 10 clock-tick)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a process to be executed more time *than the others*, you can allow it more timeslices, *without* changing the timeslice duration.

To do so, you can add some `extra_slice` and `current_slice` in `struct proc` and modify the TIMER trap handler this way:

```
if(myproc() && myproc()->state == RUNNING &&
  tf->trapno == T_IRQ0+IRQ_TIMER)
  {
    int current = myproc()->current_slice;
    if ( current ) 
      myproc()->current_slice = current - 1;
    else 
      yield();
  }
```

Then you just have to create a syscall to set `extra_slice` and modify the `scheduler` function to reset `current_slice` to `extra_slice` at process wakeup:

```
// Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job
// to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it
// before jumping back to us.
c->proc = p;
switchuvm(p);
p->state = RUNNING;
p->current_slice = p->extra_slice
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read `lapic.c` file:

```
lapicinit(void) 
{
    ....
    // The timer repeatedly counts down at bus frequency
    // from lapic[TICR] and then issues an interrupt.
    // If xv6 cared more about precise timekeeping,
    // TICR would be calibrated using an external time source.
    lapicw(TDCR, X1);
    lapicw(TIMER, PERIODIC | (T_IRQ0 + IRQ_TIMER));
    lapicw(TICR, 10000000);
```

So, if you want the timer interrupt to be more spaced, change the `TICR` value:

```
    lapicw(TICR, 10000000); //10 000 000
```

can become

```
    lapicw(TICR, 100000000); //100 000 000
```

Warning, `TICR` references a 32bits unsigned counter, do not go over `4 294 967 295` (`0xFFFFFFFF`)

Comment: And can I change this time-slices at run-time (with a system call for instance)? @Mathieu

Comment: @mahdi: the `10 000 000` is a dimension less number, the time will depend on bus frequency. For instance, if your bus is at 1Mhz, its period will be at 1us (1micro second), so your time slice will be at `1us*10 000 000 = 10 000 000 us = 10 seconds`

Comment: @mahdi Well lapic's register `TICR` controls the time slice duration, you can image to create a system call to modify it dynamically, but I'm not sure that it's supported...