# Increasing time slices for a particular process via implementing a system call in xv6

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, job-scheduling, xv6, preemption

I am trying to implement a system call in xv6 OS **Increase_time( int n)** which when executed will increase the timeslice of a program that calls it by **n** times. The default xv6 scheduler uses a simple FCFS and RR policies with each process having the same time slice. My implementation of Increase_time() will allow different processes to have different amount of time slices.

Can you please tell me a way how I can work around this?
I know how to add a system call in xv6. I just need an idea as to how I can code my system call and what files to change in xv6.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276602/how-to-modify-process-preemption-policies-like-rr-time-slices-in-xv6) question. 
In short : don't change amount of time in a slice according to the process, rather change number of timeslices received by it (refer the linked post).